# no speedup from preprocessing in blynn's PBC library

Tags: pairings

I am implementing some pairing-based cryptography protocol using [blynn's PBC library](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc).

I am only at the beginning and I wanted to confirm that [preprocessing](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual/ch03s02.html) does increase the speed. However I seem to measure only a very tiny speed up.

**Question**: Could someone tell me if this is normal and if not if there is a problem with my code ?

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/5atzBGya
As you can see it's pretty simple:
I make a thousand pairings, either using preprocessing or not
depending on the `PP` compiler macro.
If that helps I use the PBC params `d159.params`
(see [PBC manual on params](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual/ch05s01.html))

Here are the timings I get, in user time, for 1000 words:

```
    PP ON : 21.376s, 20.736s, 21.443s
    PP OFF: 22.052s, 22.788s, 22.771s
```

As you can see the difference is extremely tiny.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34971/discussion-between-cedric-van-rompay-and-artjom-b).